# WinForms: NumericUpDown (.NET CF 3.5) and real numbers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compact-framework, numericupdown

NumericUpDown seems to be only dealing with integers. How can I modify it (?), so I can use doubles as Value and Increment?

Comment: Gotta add this as a comment: NumericUpDown is probably the ugliest, clunkiest, most worthless control in Windows history. Your customers will love you if you come up with any other way of entering numbers. I understand entering numbers with the SIP (in its keyboard mode) is a pain, but if you ask the question "What's the best way to enter numbers in Windows Mobile?" I'll post the most beautiful piece of C# code I've ever encountered.

Comment: I have used slidebars next to them on the desktop to make it easier.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324559/whats-the-best-way-to-enter-numbers-in-windows-mobile-net-cf-3-5/1324599#1324599 ;)

Answer (score 2):

NumericUpDown works with decimal types, but is integer only on the compact framework.  This is a limitation of the class on CF.

There is, however, a [CodeProject UserControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15305/Decimal-UpDown-Control-for-Pocket-PC) that provides an implementation for CF.

Comment: Yes.  I just added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen it. Its textbox mishmashed with two images and a timer (!!). I have tested it and it doesn't get the input in 50% of times. I click and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I just use a textbox, then override the OnKeyPress event.  This code has worked for me in the past, but is only good for groups that write 1234.56, not 1234,56.

```
public partial class NumberTextBox : TextBox
{
    public NumberTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return decimal.Parse(Text);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public int ValueInt
    {
        get { return int.Parse(Text); }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
            && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (this).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    public void AppendString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value == "." && Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
                return;
            Text += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called DecimalPlaces.
Set it to something grater than 0 and it will allow you to work with decimals

Comment: oops, sorry didn't notice __CF__

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvote. Compact-framework wasn't one of the original tags. Jeez people.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: No, but it WAS in the original title of the question :)

Comment: @Reed: I didn't see it there, either. Also, people asking CF questions usually don't put WinForms in the title or tags, so I assumed this was full .Net too.

Answer (score 0):

My code is just one block code here it is (tested with Compact Framework);

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.')
        {
            if (((TextBox)sender).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 0)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == '\b')  // backspace silme tuşunun çalıması için gerekli
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }

        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
```

by the way, I hate Compact Framework. Because it is too Limited! But I have to :(