# Virtual Keyboard

Tags: windows-mobile, virtual-keyboard

I have an application developed to run on a particular cellphone running windows mobile. The application is configured to run in full screen using the phone physical keyboard as an interface.

At this point the client wants the application to run on cellphones that don't have a physical keyboard. This means that my application will have to use the virtual keyboard from the OS.

How can I "invoke" this keyboard so it appears on top of my application when required?

Comment: Oops, just realized you didn't necessarily say you were using .Net. If this is C++, you can still use the API call from my second answer to show/hide the SIP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The virtual keyboard in WinMo is called the SIP (Soft Input Panel).  The easiest way to show it is to place an `InputPanel` control on your form, and set its `Enabled` property to `true`.

This earlier answer has a better way (IMHO) of doing it using PInvoke:

[What's the best way to enter numbers in Windows Mobile? (.NET CF 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324559/whats-the-best-way-to-enter-numbers-in-windows-mobile-net-cf-3-5/1328365#1328365)

Note that the ungrateful #%$$@%# didn't select it (or any other answer).  :)