# Auto switch to numeric keypad on wm 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, keypad, numeric-keypad

I'm developing a software for a mobile device (Motorola ES400) with C#. Here I'm using the default wm-SIP and I don't want to change that.

There are some textboxes the user has to fill in.
My problem is, when he enters a textbox, where he should fill in only numbers he has to switch to the numeric keyboard with the  *123*-key.

I searched now quite long but I couldn't find a solution to do this automatically in the getFocus-Event.

I also tried the solution from Alex Feinman as described here: [What's the best way to enter numbers in Windows Mobile? (.NET CF 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324559/whats-the-best-way-to-enter-numbers-in-windows-mobile-net-cf-3-5) but it didn't worked either.

Is there a simle solution for this problem - Without changing the inputpanel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the solution of Alex does not work, I see no option to switch the closed source softkb.dll to numeric mode from code.

I would 
a) create my own form with numeric buttons to help the user input numbers or 
b) write my own numeric SIP (there are some out in internet, for example NumPanel form inside the book "Programming Windows CE" by Richard Boling). One can switch Input panels from code.